# Extract approximate key terms (fuzzy) from sentence in dataframe. R

Tags: r, regex, matching, stringr, fuzzy

My task is to extract specific words (the first word of the species name) from titles of journal articles. Here is a reproducible version of my dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(article_title = c("I like chickens and how to find chickens",
                     "A Horse hootio is going to the rainbow",
                     "A Cat caticus is eating cheese", 
                     "A Dog dogigo runs over a car",
                     "A Hippa potamus is in the sauna", # contains mispelling 
                     "Mos musculus found on a boat", # contains mispelling 
                     "A sentence not related to animals"))
```

The key words I want to extract are the following (with regex boundary wrappers):

```
words_to_match <- c('\\bchicken\\b', '\\bhorse\\b', '\\bcat\\b', 
                    '\\bdog\\b',
                    '\\bhippo\\b', # hippo
                    '\\bmus\\b',  # mus
                    '\\banimals\\b')
```

The problem is when I run this:

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(matched_word = stringr::str_extract_all(string = article_title, 
                                                        pattern = regex(paste(words_to_match, collapse = '|'), ignore_case = TRUE)))
```

Problem: some titles contain mispellings that are not detected.

```
                           article_title matched_word
1            Chicken chook finds a pearl      Chicken
2 A Horse hootio is going to the rainbow        Horse
3         A Cat caticus is eating cheese          Cat
4           A Dog dogigo runs over a car          Dog
5        A Hippa potamus is in the sauna             
6           Mos musculus found on a boat             
7      A sentence not related to animals      animals
```

What I want to be able to do is find a way to make another column that tells me if there is a possible match with my any `words_to_match` and perhaps the % match (Levenshtein distance).

Perhaps something like this:

```
                           article_title matched_word %
1            Chicken chook finds a pearl      Chicken 100
2 A Horse hootio is going to the rainbow        Horse 100
3         A Cat caticus is eating cheese          Cat 100
4           A Dog dogigo runs over a car          Dog 100
5        A Hippa potamus is in the sauna        Hippo XX   
6           Mos musculus found on a boat          Mus XX    
7      A sentence not related to animals      animals 100
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated even if it is not using `R`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `adist` to find approximately matches:

```
x <- adist(words_to_match, df$article_title, fixed=FALSE, ignore.case = TRUE)
i <- apply(x, 1, which.min)
df$matched_word <- words_to_match[i]
df$adist <- mapply("[", asplit(x, 2), i)
df
#                             article_title  matched_word adist
#1 I like chickens and how to find chickens \\bchicken\\b     2
#2   A Horse hootio is going to the rainbow   \\bhorse\\b     0
#3           A Cat caticus is eating cheese     \\bcat\\b     0
#4             A Dog dogigo runs over a car     \\bdog\\b     0
#5          A Hippa potamus is in the sauna   \\bhippo\\b     1
#6             Mos musculus found on a boat     \\bmus\\b     1
#7        A sentence not related to animals \\banimals\\b     0
```

Comment: Hey @GKi, thanks for the suggestion. This is definitely going the right track. One issue I have is in my real dataset, my `words_to_match` vector is much larger than than the length of `df$article`. Is there a way to work around this issue?

Comment: This should not cause a problem when your `words_to_match` vector is much larger than than the length of `df$article_title`. What error do you get?

Answer (score 2):

You could put the words plain into a vector `wm` and `strsplit` each sentence. Then in an `lapply` use `adist` to get a distance matrix  of each word to each element `wm`. The minimum should give you the best match. I'm not sure about your rationale of levenshtein distance (LD) in percents, though.

```
wm <- c("chicken", "horse", "cat", "dog", "hippo", "mus", "animals")

dl <- strsplit(df$article_title, " ")

res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(dl, function(x) {
  e  <- adist(tolower(x), wm)
  mins <- apply(e, 2, min)
  emin <- which.min(mins)
  data.frame(matched_word=wm[emin], LD=mins[emin])
}))
res
#   matched_word LD
# 1      chicken  1
# 2        horse  0
# 3          cat  0
# 4          dog  0
# 5        hippo  1
# 6          mus  1
# 7      animals  0
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(article_title = c("I like chickens and how to find chickens", 
"A Horse hootio is going to the rainbow", "A Cat caticus is eating cheese", 
"A Dog dogigo runs over a car", "A Hippa potamus is in the sauna", 
"Mos musculus found on a boat", "A sentence not related to animals"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```